# Too many actual parameters for macro?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define ADD(x,y)  ((x)+(y))

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    cout << ADD(1,2,) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

> 1>Compiling...
>       1>main.cpp
>       1>c:\warn_test\main.cpp(9) : warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'ADD'

Why isn't this an error?

`g++ (GCC) 4.2.1 20070719  [FreeBSD]` gives more reasonable (in my mind) output:

> main.cpp:9:18: error: macro "ADD" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
>       main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>       main.cpp:9: error: 'ADD' was not declared in this scope

Though I'm not entirely sure what either compiler thinks the third argument is.

EDIT: Added complete `gcc` output and version info.

Comment: I suspect no very good reason, the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y37zb304 indicates that it varies by compiler version whether it's a warning or an error. Maybe to support some dodgy legacy code somewhere that relies on it only being a warning. The third argument is a 0-length sequence of tokens, which could be substituted into a macro expansion if there was a third macro argument. Note the standard allows implementations to compile invalid code with any implementation-specific meaning they like, provided they issue a diagnostic, so it's "quirky" rather than "wrong".

Comment: What is an error or a warning is configurable. Is your complaint that different compilers have different defaults? That would be easy to fix in your project settings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `ADD(1,2,)`, note the second `,`. Remove that and it will compile just fine!

@schnaader: You are right, I read too fast. Sorry.

[edit]
Please provide more details about the compiler in question. I use: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5, and this is the result I get:

```
test.cpp:9: error: macro "ADD" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:9: error: ‘ADD’ was not declared in this scope
```

[edit2]
Sorry, again a bit too fast :-). I see you tagged it with visual studio. VS is more tolerant than g++. I suppose that -- because it is easy to resolve in this case -- it automatically corrects it.

Comment: @schnaader: Exactly.  The warning behavior struck me as extremely counter-intuitive.  I wanted to know if there was some aspect of the C++ spec that would allow Microsoft to not error out in this case.

Comment: Edited my question with the complete `gcc` version and output.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to throw out a complete guess, inspired by Steve Jessop's comment that it's related to variadic macro support.

Possibly it was easier to make it a warning when the visual studio team implemented variadic macros? I've noticed varying levels of tolerance when implementing code like:

```
#define MACRO(...) my_func(true, __VA_ARGS__);

MACRO(1,,2); // Missing argument
MACRO(1,); // missing tail
MACRO(); // no arguments
```

Some compilers error, warn or ignore the various situations. I don't know what the standards says tho.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is somewhat compiler's choice. If there was a third parameter, it would perhaps be more problematic, but as there isn't, you can argue about just ignoring the comma or throwing an error. Microsoft seems to be more error tolerant often (like in IE HTML parsing).