# c++ macro and lambda capture

Tags: c++, lambda, macros, capture

When I use a lambda in a macro with multiple captures, I encounter one of these errors *(Visual Studio 2017)* :
`Error C2143 syntax error: missing ']' before ';'`
`Error C2958 the left bracket '['`

How can I avoid this error?

Code example :

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#define MYMACRO(lambda) lambda

int main()
{
    int a = 13;
    int b = 37;
    auto lambda = MYMACRO([a, b]() { std::cout << a << b << std::endl; });
    lambda();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need macros? I never had to use them in a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted elsewhere, the actual bug is that `MYMACRO` as written only expects a single argument. Unless enclosed by parentheses or quotes, commas are used to delineate separate arguments to a macro invocation.

A lambda may have multiple commas in the capture brackets, so `MYMACRO` actually needs to be able to handle variable arguments if you want to leave the invocation syntax the same as you have in your program. This is possible since C++11, which added support for variadic macros.

Visual Studio 2017 supports the variadic macro syntax. So, you could change your macro to be:

```
#define MYMACRO(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

Note that the variable arguments can only appear at the end of the macro arguments specification.

Answer (score 3):

GCC gives a slightly more friendly error message:

> 10:73: error: macro "MYMACRO" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1

The commas in your lambda declaration are being interpreted as delimiting arguments to the macro. You need to wrap the expression in brackets:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#define MYMACRO(lambda) lambda

int main()
{
    int a = 13;
    int b = 37;
    auto lambda = MYMACRO(([a, b]() { std::cout << a << b << std::endl; }));
    lambda();
    return 0;
}
```

Visual studio raises a warning then ignores spurious macro arguments so your code is equivalent to:

```
auto lambda = MYMACRO([a);
```

Which makes the error message more understandable. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4002

Comment: Ok thank you. It looks like a bad interpretation by the compilers of the lambda capture in the macro? Do you think this behavior will be fixed? Or will persist?

Comment: The compilers are doing exactly the right thing which is whatever they like, passing additional parameters to a macro is undefined behaviour.

Comment: The compilers are allowed to ignore invalid code as long as they emit some form of diagnostic error so visual studio isn't incorrect, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248599/too-many-actual-parameters-for-macro